Performance improvement: Azure Synapse stored procedure
I need suggestions on the stored procedure, it basically compares the live data with the backup data based on some condition(s).
So difference = (A-B) + (B-A)
Here's my attempt: my idea is to store the result of A in a single temp variable and similar with B, and then do #tempA - #tempB and store the result.
CREATE PROCEDURE [ALT].[USP_SUPPL_COMPARE_DIM_LEASE_ACTIVITY] 
    @BKP_QUARTERS [NVARCHAR](7), 
    @LATEST_DATE_VALUE [NVARCHAR](6) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL_a NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @SQL_b NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQL_a = 
        '
    SELECT DIM.LEASE_ACTIVITY_KEY, DIM.LEASE_ACTIVITY_SRC_KEY, DIM.CONTRACT_NUMBER, DIM.LEASE_REPORTING_TYPE, DIM.TRANSACTION_TYPE, DIM.LEASE_TYPE, DIM.ACTIVITY_STATUS, DIM.LEASE_DESCRIPTION, DIM.LEASE_COMMENTS, DIM.REPORT_DATE, DIM.START_DATE, DIM.END_DATE, DIM.SIGN_DATE, DIM.START_DATE_KEY, DIM.END_DATE_KEY, DIM.SIGN_DATE_KEY, DIM.LEASE_COMMENCEMENT_DATE, DIM.ORIGINAL_TERM_EXPIRATION_DATE, DIM.EXPIRATION_DATE, DIM.CONTRACTUAL_START_DATE, DIM.SUITES, DIM.RENEWAL_TYPE, DIM.CONTRACTUAL_RENT_START_DATE, DIM.RENT_START_DATE, DIM.ORIGINAL_TERM_END_DATE, DIM.REPORTED_FLAG, DIM.RENT_TREND_EXCLUDED_FLAG, DIM.NON_LEASE_DEAL, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_DATE_STATUS, DIM.RETENTION_TYPE, DIM.GENERATION, DIM.CASH__RENT__STABILIZES, DIM.RELEASE_FLAG, DIM.PUBLISHED_FLAG, DIM.PRODUCT_TYPE, DIM.CROSS_CONNECT_TYPE, DIM.BUSINESS_UNIT, DIM.TELX_CASE_NUMBER, DIM.LEASE_CURRENCY_CODE, DIM.LEASE_EXCHANGE_RATE, DIM.SIGN_PERIOD, DIM.REPORT_PERIOD, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_PERIOD, DIM.SIGN_YEAR, DIM.REPORT_YEAR, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_YEAR, DIM.REDUNDANCY, DIM.DATASOURCE, DIM.SOURCE, DIM.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER, DIM.PUBLISHED_LEASE_IDENTIFIER, DIM.CUSTOMER_TYPE, DIM.YARDI_TCODE, DIM.UNIT_TYPE, DIM.LEGACY_SRC_KEY, DIM.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROUP, DIM.UNIT_TYPE_SRC_KEY, DIM.EXCLUDE_FROM_LEASESTATS, DIM.LOCK_FLAG, DIM.ORDER_START_DATE, DIM.FNT_ASSET_ID, DIM.MTM_FLAG, DIM.PRIOR_LEASE_MRC, DIM.OPERATION_CODE, DIM.RECORDONLY_FLAG, DIM.LEASE_CREATED_BY, DIM.LEASE_OWNER, DIM.POWER_TYPE, DIM.TRANSACTION_SUBTYPE, DIM.ANNUAL_ESCALATION_TYPE__C, DIM.CPI_CAP__C, DIM.ESCALATION_TYPE_COMMENTS__C
INTO #TempLeaseActivity_a
    FROM DWH.DIM_LEASE_ACTIVITY DIM
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM_DATE D ON (CASE WHEN DIM.LEASE_REPORTING_TYPE = ''Signed Leases'' THEN DIM.SIGN_DATE_KEY ELSE DIM.START_DATE_KEY END) = D.DATE_KEY
    WHERE D.QUARTER = ''' 
        + @BKP_QUARTERS + ''' 
      AND (DIM.DATASOURCE NOT IN (''Teraco Upload'', ''INXN FTP'') OR (DIM.DATASOURCE IN (''Teraco Upload'', ''INXN FTP'') AND DIM.COMMENCEMENT_DATE_STATUS <> ''Target''))
'
    SET @SQL_b = 
        '
    SELECT DIM.LEASE_ACTIVITY_KEY, DIM.LEASE_ACTIVITY_SRC_KEY, DIM.CONTRACT_NUMBER, DIM.LEASE_REPORTING_TYPE, DIM.TRANSACTION_TYPE, DIM.LEASE_TYPE, DIM.ACTIVITY_STATUS, DIM.LEASE_DESCRIPTION, DIM.LEASE_COMMENTS, DIM.REPORT_DATE, DIM.START_DATE, DIM.END_DATE, DIM.SIGN_DATE, DIM.START_DATE_KEY, DIM.END_DATE_KEY, DIM.SIGN_DATE_KEY, DIM.LEASE_COMMENCEMENT_DATE, DIM.ORIGINAL_TERM_EXPIRATION_DATE, DIM.EXPIRATION_DATE, DIM.CONTRACTUAL_START_DATE, DIM.SUITES, DIM.RENEWAL_TYPE, DIM.CONTRACTUAL_RENT_START_DATE, DIM.RENT_START_DATE, DIM.ORIGINAL_TERM_END_DATE, DIM.REPORTED_FLAG, DIM.RENT_TREND_EXCLUDED_FLAG, DIM.NON_LEASE_DEAL, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_DATE_STATUS, DIM.RETENTION_TYPE, DIM.GENERATION, DIM.CASH__RENT__STABILIZES, DIM.RELEASE_FLAG, DIM.PUBLISHED_FLAG, DIM.PRODUCT_TYPE, DIM.CROSS_CONNECT_TYPE, DIM.BUSINESS_UNIT, DIM.TELX_CASE_NUMBER, DIM.LEASE_CURRENCY_CODE, DIM.LEASE_EXCHANGE_RATE, DIM.SIGN_PERIOD, DIM.REPORT_PERIOD, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_PERIOD, DIM.SIGN_YEAR, DIM.REPORT_YEAR, DIM.COMMENCEMENT_YEAR, DIM.REDUNDANCY, DIM.DATASOURCE, DIM.SOURCE, DIM.ORDER_LINE_NUMBER, DIM.PUBLISHED_LEASE_IDENTIFIER, DIM.CUSTOMER_TYPE, DIM.YARDI_TCODE, DIM.UNIT_TYPE, DIM.LEGACY_SRC_KEY, DIM.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROUP, DIM.UNIT_TYPE_SRC_KEY, DIM.EXCLUDE_FROM_LEASESTATS, DIM.LOCK_FLAG, DIM.ORDER_START_DATE, DIM.FNT_ASSET_ID, DIM.MTM_FLAG, DIM.PRIOR_LEASE_MRC, DIM.OPERATION_CODE, DIM.RECORDONLY_FLAG, DIM.LEASE_CREATED_BY, DIM.LEASE_OWNER, DIM.POWER_TYPE, DIM.TRANSACTION_SUBTYPE, DIM.ANNUAL_ESCALATION_TYPE__C, DIM.CPI_CAP__C, DIM.ESCALATION_TYPE_COMMENTS__C
INTO #TempLeaseActivity_b
    FROM SCRATCH.DIM_LEASE_ACTIVITY_DLY_BKP_' 
        + @LATEST_DATE_VALUE + ' AS DIM
    INNER JOIN DWH.DIM_DATE D ON (CASE WHEN DIM.LEASE_REPORTING_TYPE = ''Signed Leases'' THEN DIM.SIGN_DATE_KEY ELSE DIM.START_DATE_KEY END) = D.DATE_KEY
    WHERE D.QUARTER = ''' + @BKP_QUARTERS + ''' 
      AND (DIM.DATASOURCE NOT IN (''Teraco Upload'', ''INXN FTP'') OR (DIM.DATASOURCE IN (''Teraco Upload'', ''INXN FTP'') AND DIM.COMMENCEMENT_DATE_STATUS <> ''Target''))
'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_a;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_b;

    INSERT INTO [ALT].[SUPPL_DLY_BACKUP_COMPARE] (
        TABLE_NAME
        ,TYPE
        ,COUNT
        ,QUARTER
        ,COMPARED_WITH_BKP_DATE
        ,ETL_CREATED_DT
        )
    SELECT NAME
        ,TYPE
        ,COUNT
        ,QUARTER
        ,COMPARED_WITH_BKP_DATE
        ,GETDATE() AS ETL_CREATED_DT
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
            ,'Lease Activity Dimension' AS NAME
            ,'Live minus Backup' AS TYPE
            ,@BKP_QUARTERS AS QUARTER
            ,FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMMdd') AS COMPARED_WITH_BKP_DATE
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM #TempLeaseActivity_a
            
            EXCEPT
            
            SELECT *
            FROM #TempLeaseActivity_b
            ) T
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
            ,'Lease Activity Dimension' AS NAME
            ,'Backup minus Live' AS TYPE
            ,@BKP_QUARTERS AS QUARTER
            ,FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyMMdd') AS COMPARED_WITH_BKP_DATE
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM #TempLeaseActivity_b
            
            EXCEPT
            
            SELECT *
            FROM #TempLeaseActivity_a
            ) T1
        ) C;
END;


This question would benefit from having sample data and expected outcome. Why do you want to store into variables before comparing ? Why not compare direct in your query ?

This query can't work at all, because #t-tables are lost when you leave the dynamic sql context. But otherwise, i don't see any great way of improving this, you might first join on PK perhaps to see where rows completely differ, but not sure if it gains that much, how many rows eventually end up in those #t-tables?

have you tried using ##temptable instead of #temptable?

@GuidoG we have so many column in that table that when running sp_execute is fails to take entire sql (a-b) and fails because it truncates the code.

running sp_execute is fails to take entire sql (a-b) and fails because it truncates the code That is not mentioned in your question, so what is your question now ?
